# How do Brits pronounce [ee] in "queen" differently to [i] in "pita"?

Tags: british-english, vowels

[This explanation of Welsh pronunciation](http://www.go4awalk.com/fell-facts/welsh-language-pronunciation.php#w) says Welsh **u** is pronounced like **i** in p**i**ta, whereas Welsh **i** is pronounced like **ee** in Qu**ee**n.

What's the difference?

Comment: [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/search/british/direct/?q=pita) says that in the U.K., the 'i' in *pita* is pronounced the same way as the 'i' in *bitter*. Considering the U.S. pronunciation, this was a unfortunate choice of word to use as an example.

Comment: @PeterShor Or how Greeks pronounce πίτα … http://www.forvo.com/word/%CF%80%CE%AF%CF%84%CE%B1/

Comment: Here in the UK, the i in pita is pronounced like the i in bit.

Comment: Right, as AmE, I'm thinking pita as peeta.

Comment: This doesn't address the pita/queen part of your question, but perhaps it will be useful: In Welsh, "u" is often pronounced /ɨ/ and "i" is pronounced /i/.

Comment: @JustinGreer Thanks, it's actually even more topical than my actual question. So ɨ is it like the Polish y? (`zloty`)

Comment: @isomorphismes Yes, basically. [ɨ] is also the same as the _e_ in ‘roses’ in English. The description in your link is inaccurate, though. Both _i_ and _u_ (and _y_, for that matter) can be either long or short, and the pronunciation of _u_ depends on dialect. When short, _i_ is [ɪ] (as in ‘bit’); when long, it’s [iː] (as in ‘queen’). In northern dialects, short _u_ is [ɨ̞] (more or less as in ‘roses’ or _złoty_), long _u_ is [ɨː]; in the South, it is pronounced like _i_, whether long or short.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks! Two in one go! I've wondered about Polish ɨ for years.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody's answered but rather only commented … apparently it's:

- "pitta", rhyming with German `bitte`

Comment: For people who don't speak German, it rhymes with the English word *bitter*, as Peter Shor commented yesterday. Note that *pit(t)ta* and *bitter*  rhyme perfectly only in non-rhotic varieties of British English. Note also that some speakers of BrE pronounce *pit(t)a* in exactly the same way as they pronounce Mr Shor's first name. As he noted, "... this was an unfortunate choice of word to use as an example."

Comment: Might I suggest expanding on this a bit to explain that the difference between queen and pita is that pita in BrE rhymes with bitter. But the original question is based upon a premise that would be correct only in a specific localization.

Answer (score -1):

Pita in English with a British Accent is pronounced like Bitter. we don't pronounce words with one (I) like they have 2 (ee) in the word, we pronounce as it is spelt. We pronounce QUEEN that way as it has 2 (ee) in.
I hope this helps.

Comment: British people never pronounce words spelled with a single "i" using the sound of "ee"? I don't think that's right. How do you pronounce "kiwi," "pique," and "marine" differently from "keewi," "peek," and "mareen"?

Comment: So *vita* rhymes with *pita*?